# drop-down menu using dropit.js

Tags: css

I created a drop down menu using dropit.js that worked just fine. I tried to duplicate it for my account settings menu and it doesn't seem to be carrying over with CSS.

This is my HTML:

```
   <ul id="top-nav" class="settings menu">
     <li><img src="twitter/idiot/128.jpg" alt="avatar"></li>

     <li><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/idiot/128.jpg">Sam Yanow I</a></li>
      <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Account Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Collaborators</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Upgrade</a></li>

          </ul>

     <li class="btn-outline"><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
   </ul>
```

This is the JS associated at the bottom:

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(".menu").dropit();`

[A link to dropit.css](https://github.com/samyanow/Blocbox/blob/gh-pages/CSS/dropit.css).

[A link to the dropit.js](https://github.com/samyanow/Blocbox/blob/gh-pages/JS/dropit.js).

Answer (score 0):

You closed the LI, then added what should be a child of the LI inside the UL as a sibling of LI.

The child UL should be inside the LI.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyzroupk/)**

```
 <li><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/idiot/128.jpg">
        Sam Yanow I
     </a><!-- remove this </li> -->
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Account Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Collaborators</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Upgrade</a></li>

     </ul>
</li><!--  it belongs here -->
```